# How to secure a connection(s) that integrate Apache Spark?

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, cluster-computing

I would like to ask about how of secure a connection between the clusters that use apache spark, mainly the spark-shell and any other java client that uses the spark cluster ?

I would like to avoid using YARN or Mesos, since it might complicate everything without a necessity.

I am aware of this information:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SecurityManager.html

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html

Nevertheless, I would like to see some implementation examples.
Thank you !

Comment: This page summarizes the current support: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html

Comment: yes, I know about it :)  however, I was expecting that there is more information/details than what they have mentioned.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is in config page not the security page:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html